# How to install Eclipse Luna IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, programming-languages, eclipse-luna

I'm trying to install eclipse Luna on my pc, but it show error all the time. I've searched on many websites and found that there's something to do with configuration settings. Please help me by providing  step by step instructions.!
[Screenshots below shows the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAbx9.jpg)

Comment: Please describe the error, or provide some screenshots.

Comment: I'll help you if you can help me with my car. It's broken.

Comment: That is a very unclear and overly-broad questions. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/review)

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: Plz check the above screenshot.

Comment: Do you have the right java version? This error can happen when you try to start a 32 bit java on a 64 bit os.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the version of JDK and Eclipse, the both need match that if you installed 64bit Eclipse then you need 64bit JDK.